# AngularJS: Requiring a parent directive from child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please consider this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rKw8P549WkpJhlZ9O72v?p=preview).

I'm trying to set up a test case for complex directive access, but I get an error calling a method from the parent directive:

*Parent directive*

```
app.directive('topParentDirective', [
    '$compile',
    function($compile){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<h3>I\'m the parent directive.</h3><div ng-transclude></div>',
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.ActivateMe = function(callerName) {
            alert('Parent activated from caller ' + callerName);
          };
        }
      };
    }
]);
```

*Child directive*

```
app.directive('interactingChildDirective', [
    '$compile',
    function($compile){
      return {
        scope: {
          name: '@'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^topParentDirective'],
        templateUrl: 'interactingChildDirective.html',
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
          var self = {};

          console.log($ctrl);

          $scope.CallTopParent = function() {
            $ctrl.ActivateMe($attrs.name);
          };
        }
      };
    }
]);
```

*InteractingChildDirective.html*

Contains:

```
My name is {{name}}, <button ng-click="CallTopParent()">Click me</button>!
```

*Html*

```
<body ng-app="ngApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <top-parent-directive>
    <interacting-child-directive name="Child 1"></interacting-child-directive>
  </top-parent-directive>
</div>
</body>
```

***Issue***

```
TypeError: $ctrl.ActivateMe is not a function
    at n.$scope.CallTopParent
```

Which is the case because $ctrl doesn't seem to be correct.

How can I fix this? It's likely something ridiculously easy ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.ActivateMe = function(callerName) {
        alert('Parent activated from caller ' + callerName);
      };
    }
```

Because $ctrl gets required controller's `this`.

Comment: I just tried this in his plunkr and could not get it to work - is there anything else needed outside of the code you provided?

Comment: That's because `require: ['^topParentDirective']` implies that you're about to require several controllers, you have to use `$ctrl[0].ActivateMe` in this case. Otherwise stick to `require: '^topParentDirective'` for a single required controller.

Comment: You mean changing the ActivateMe definition, within topParentDirective, to use this.ActivateMe instead? That's what I tried, no change.

Comment: I got it to work on my original Plunk while you posted your comment apparently. I did try $ctrl[0] previously but it didn't work. Anyway, this works.

Comment: Could you expand on why -this- is required? It doesn't feel very intuitive to me.

Comment: $ctrl[0] [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/aVKebmQRxqcazKKjyL0y?p=preview) as well but is unnecessary in this case. Generally you would name the var 'ctrls' to hint that it contains an array. 'require' gets controller's instance, it is the object that is referred by 'this' in controller construction function. You may also check [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) on 'require', 'controller' and 'link' sections.

Comment: Pretty sweet - thanks for explaining - adding this to my arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have nested the child in the parents controller you can access it's scope by using

```
$scope.$parent
```

in your case:

```
$scope.$parent.ActivateMe($attrs.name);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YyppT9pWnn1PFWJXBAOF?p=info

Comment: I'm reluctant to do that because the scenario I am investigating will be far more complex, I want something like this: A, B, C, B. Where A in this case is topParentDirective and B is interactingChildDirective. The point is that the second B should always find the top A, not C.

Comment: Ahh I see, if it isn't too complex to explain it may help us provide a better answer if we knew what complications you see could arise.

Comment: I'll use the $parent scenario to get the test working and update once I get stuck again :) (I was editing while you commented, apparently).

Comment: So the second B is nested 4 down if I understand? Does it need to have C's scope or does it only need A's? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Correct, that second B instance would need A only (as far as I can see now, at least).

Comment: Then I think you should be good to go using parent as it isn't going to be told to require C - though you have me thinking if C needs access to A you may have to do $scope.$parent.$parent - I don't actually know if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by estus, combined by the comments, works. To be complete, a working sample of the scenario I was aiming for:

Plunkr [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/jiFNRak7N5UaMFq2baIy?p=preview).

*Updated Html*

```
<body ng-app="ngApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <top-parent-directive>

        <interacting-child-directive name="Child 1">

          <meaningless-level-directive header="Sub 1">
            <interacting-child-directive name="Child 3"/>
          </meaningless-level-directive>

        </interacting-child-directive>

        <interacting-child-directive name="Child 2">

          <meaningless-level-directive header="Sub 2">
            <interacting-child-directive name="Child 4"/>
          </meaningless-level-directive>

        </interacting-child-directive>

      </top-parent-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

*meaninglessLevelDirective*

As the name suggests this is just to add an extra level:

```
app.directive('meaninglessLevelDirective', [
  '$compile',
  function($compile){
    return {
      scope: {
        header: '@'
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'meaninglessLevelDirective.html',
      controller: function($scope){
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

*meaninglessLevelDirective.html*

```
<div class="meaninglessLevelStyle">
  {{header}}
  <div style="padding: 10px" ng-transclude>
  </div>  
</div>
```